# create a table without hardcode in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a ten row five column table which has only two rows filled in it and also first cell of every row has a checkbox. I want to write entire table code in script of jquery but not define it as hardcode  data  in html page. I want it as an array instead of individual variables for each row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = [

{ 
  check: '<label><input type="checkbox" class="case" /><span></span>
  </label>',
  name: 'XYZ',
  score: '<div class="score">34</div>',
},
{ 
  check: '<label><input type="checkbox" class="case" /><span></span>
  </label>',
  name: 'XYZ',
  score: '<div class="score">34</div>',
},
{ 
  check: '<label><input type="checkbox" class="case" /><span></span>
  </label>',
  name: 'XYZ',
  score: '<div class="score">34</div>',
},

 $.each(table, function(index, obj)
 {
var row = '<tr>';
row += '<td>' + obj.check + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + obj.name + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + obj.score + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + obj.mail + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + obj.other + '</td>';
$('tbody').append(row);
});
```

I dont want to declare objects every time. I want to use an array for defining "name, score, mail, other" and then push related items into that array variables

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and show us what you have got so far.

Comment: share the code which you have tried

Comment: this "question" does not contain a question. This is just a wishlist. What have you researched? What have you tried? What are you stuck with? This is not a free write-my-code service, it's a site for troubleshooting the code you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the loop by folowing code

```
  $.each(table, function(index, obj)
     {
       var row = '<tr>';
       var keys = Object.keys(obj);
       $.each(keys, function(index, val){
         row += '<td>' + obj[val] + '</td>';
      });
      row += '</tr>';
      $('tbody').append(row);
    });
```

here you can see how an object could be iterated to get all the key-values,so you wouldn't need to explicitly write obj.name, obj.type etc.

Comment: Please make an effort to explain what the code does and how it could help @Manoj. Code only answers are seen as low quality and may be deleted.

Comment: well,i thought that answer was too precise and simple to be explained. But anyhow i have edited it. 
Thnx for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this should provide what you need. Everything, including the columns, headings and contents, number of rows to render, and data to display is configured via an array of elements. There's no hard-coded HTML as such, it can all be manipulated via JavaScript.

I hope this is useful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//pre-defined array of columns and their base content
var cols = {
  "Check": $("<input/>", { "type": "checkbox", "class": "case" }),
  "Name": $("<span/>", { html: "&nbsp;" }),
  "Score": $("<div/>", { "class": "score" }), 
  "Mail": $("<span/>", { html: "&nbsp;" }), 
  "Other": $("<span/>", { html: "&nbsp;" })
};

var trows = 10; //total rows to render
var data =
[
 { "Name": "ABC", "Score": 34, "Mail": "xyz", "Other": "blah" },
 { "Name": "DEF", "Score": 43, "Mail": "iii", "Other": "fff"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < trows; i++)
{
  var tr = $("<tr/>");
  
  $.each(cols, function(prop, element)
  {
    //only create the header once
    if (i == 0)
    {
      var th = $("<th/>", { "text": prop });
      $("#table1 thead tr").append(th);
    }

    var td = $("<td/>");
    
    if (element)
    {
      var cellContent = element.clone();
      if (data[i] && data[i][prop])
      {
        cellContent.text(data[i][prop]);
      }
      td.append(cellContent);
    }
    tr.append(td);
  });
  
  $("#table1 tbody").append(tr);
}

});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th { border: solid 1px #cccccc; padding:10px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: var data =
[
 { "Name": "ABC", "Score": 34, "Mail": "xyz", "Other": "blah" },
 { "Name": "DEF", "Score": 43, "Mail": "iii", "Other": "fff"}
];

Comment: Is there any other way instead of writing like this for every row

Comment: and finally how can i find the max and avg of selected employees' scores

Comment: What don't you like about that way of writing it? That's the shortest way to store the data in JavaScript / JSON. To get the max and avg of the scores you'd have to loop through the items in the array, and find the max / avg using regular maths. It's just a case of a loop and some sums.

Comment: @ManojKumar What did you decide with this? If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks :-)